# Как поменять цвет текста в JList при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: java, swing

Пишу простенький ToDo List.
Нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Выполнено", текст, в JList, становился зелёного цвета.
Вот код:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Window extends JFrame {

    private JTextField input = new JTextField("");
    private JButton addBtn = new JButton("Добавить");
    private JButton deleteBtn = new JButton("Удалить");
    private JButton completeBtn = new JButton("Выполнено");
    private ArrayList<String> missions = new ArrayList<>();
    private DefaultListModel<String> dlm = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    private JList<String> list = new JList<String>(dlm);

    Window() {
        super("ToDo List");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setBounds(100,100,600,200);
        Container container = this.getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 3));
        addBtn.addActionListener(new AddActionListener());
        deleteBtn.addActionListener(new DeleteActionListener());
        container.add(input);
        container.add(addBtn);
        container.add(deleteBtn);
        container.add(completeBtn);
        container.add(new JScrollPane(list));
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class AddActionListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            dlm.add(dlm.getSize(), input.getText());
        }
    }

    class DeleteActionListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            dlm.remove(list.getSelectedIndex());
        }
    }

    class CompleteActionListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Не знаю как реализовать данный класс
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для кастомизации отображения `JList` есть возможность установить свой `ListCellRenderer`, внутри которого у Вас есть возможность определить по модели данных, как должна выглядеть отрисовываемая в данный момент ячейка, вот пример:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Window extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Window();
    }

    private JTextField input = new JTextField();
    private JButton addBtn = new JButton("Добавить");
    private JButton deleteBtn = new JButton("Удалить");
    private JButton completeBtn = new JButton("Выполнено");
    private DefaultListModel<Mission> dlm = new DefaultListModel<>();
    private JList<Mission> list = new JList<>(dlm);

    Window() {
        super("ToDo List");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 600, 200);
        Container container = this.getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 3));
        list.setCellRenderer(new CustomListRenderer());
        addBtn.addActionListener(new AddActionListener());
        deleteBtn.addActionListener(new DeleteActionListener());
        completeBtn.addActionListener(new CompleteActionListener());
        container.add(input);
        container.add(addBtn);
        container.add(deleteBtn);
        container.add(completeBtn);
        container.add(new JScrollPane(list));
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class AddActionListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            dlm.add(dlm.getSize(), new Mission(input.getText()));
        }
    }

    class DeleteActionListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            dlm.remove(list.getSelectedIndex());
        }
    }

    class CompleteActionListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Mission mission = dlm.get(list.getSelectedIndex());
            mission.completed = !mission.completed;
            list.repaint();
        }
    }

    private class CustomListRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            JLabel renderer = (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            Mission m = (Mission) value;
            renderer.setText(m.text);
            renderer.setBackground(m.completed ? Color.GREEN: Color.WHITE);
            return renderer;
        }
    }

    private class Mission {
        String text;
        boolean completed;

        Mission(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }
    }
}
```